# How to inserting multiple records into mysql using query builder laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How to inserting multiple records into mysql using query builder laravel ? i try use `insert->()` to insert records to mysql table, but it just inserting 1 value.i've try to read some article about inserting multiple records, but its not just like i want

1. my controller

   ```
   public function postBuy(Request $request)
   {
   $data = array();
   $data['products_id']= $request->get('products_id');
   $data['products']   = $request->get('products');
   $data['price']      = $request->get('price');
   $data['user_id']    = $request->get('user_id');
   $data['user_name']  = $request->get('user_name');
   $data['user_email'] = $request->get('user_email');

   $query_insert = DB::table('cashier')->insert($data);

   return redirect('index');
   }
   ```
2. my forms

   ```
      <form method="POST" action='{{ url("buy") }}' enctype="multipart/form-data">  
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
         <table class="table table-stripped">
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Product</th>
               <th>Price</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
           @foreach($item as $items)
           <input type="hidden" name="products_id" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{$items->id}}" readonly="readonly">
             <tr>
               <td>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="text" name="products" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{$items->name}}" readonly="readonly">
                 </div>                      
               </td>
               <td>
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{$items->price}}" readonly="readonly">
                 </div>
               </td>
             </tr>
           @endforeach
             <tr>
               <td>Total :</td>
               <td><?php echo number_format($total) ;?></td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>
         <div class="form-group">
           <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{Session::get('id')}}">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <input type="hidden" name="user_name" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{Session::get('name')}}">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
           <input type="hidden" name="user_email" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{Session::get('email')}}">
         </div>
         <br>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Buy</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</button>
       </form>
   ```
3. my records in view which will be inserting in mysql table
   [image: modal view]
4. i want insert that 2 records into my cashier table, but it just inserting 1 records
   [image: cashier table]

Comment: You can use array and foreach function

Comment: @Jigs1212 can you explain more specific ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really easy to do a bulk insert in Laravel using Eloquent or the query builder.

You can use the following approach:

```
public function postBuy(Request $request)
{
   $data = array(
      array('products_id'=> $request->get('products_id'), 'products'=> $request->get('products'), 'price'=> $request->get('price'), 'user_id'=> $request->get('user_id'), 'user_name'=> $request->get('user_name'), 'user_email'=> $request->get('user_email')),
      array('products_id'=> $request->get('products_id'), 'products'=> $request->get('products'), 'price'=> $request->get('price'), 'user_id'=> $request->get('user_id'), 'user_name'=> $request->get('user_name'), 'user_email'=> $request->get('user_email'),
      //...
   );

    $query_insert = DB::table('cashier')->insert($data);
    return redirect('index');

    //For info
    Model::insert($data); // Eloquent approach
    DB::table('cashier')->insert($data); // Query Builder approach as you are using
}
```

**EDIT :**

In your case, you need to take `[]` in your every input field in your form! Like:

`name="products_id[]"`, `name="products[]"`, `name="price[]"`

**EDIT 2 :**

You can add multiple records using `foreach` like:

```
foreach ($request as $key=>$value)
{
    $data[] = [
        'products_id' => $value['products_id'],
        'products' => $value['products'],
        'price' => $value['price'],
        'user_id' => $value['user_id'],
        'user_name' => $value['user_name'],
        'user_email' =>  $value['user_email']
    ];
}

DB::table('cashier')->insert($data); // Query Builder approach as you are using
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You're sending your inputs with the same name, so laravel doesn't recieve them as  arrays.

For example

```
@foreach($item as $items)
    <input type="hidden" name="products_id[]" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{$items->id}}" readonly="readonly">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="products[]" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{$items->name}}" readonly="readonly">
        </div>                      
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{$items->price}}" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

In the controller:

```
$data = array();
$data['products_id']= $request->get('products_id');
$data['products']   = $request->get('products');
$data['price']      = $request->get('price');
$insertData = collect($data);
$insertData->prepend($request->get('user_id'), 'user_id');
$insertData->prepend($request->get('user_name'), 'user_name');
$insertData->prepend($request->get('user_email'), 'user_email');

$query_insert = DB::table('cashier')->insert($insertData);
```

Comment: Note the added `[]` in the form

Comment: get an error, 'Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, object given' , in controller this line '$query_insert = DB::table('cashier')->insert($insertData);'